# Access array in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I have JavaScript calculator wherein I have defined two arrays as follows:

```
var degInc, degArr = []; 
var radInc, radArr = [];
var PI = Math.PI;
var radStart = (-91*PI/2), radEnd = (91*PI/2);

 for (degInc = -8190; degInc <= 8190; degInc+=180) {
       degArr.push(degInc);
    }
 for (radInc = radStart; radInc <= radEnd; radInc+=PI) {
        var radIncFixed = radInc.toFixed(8);
       radArr.push(radIncFixed);
    }
```

to be used in conjunction with the tangent function (below) so as to display a value of `Undefined` in an input (HTML below) should the user attempt to take the tangent of these values (I have included other relavent function as well):

Input -

```
<INPUT NAME="display" ID="disp" VALUE="0" SIZE="28" MAXLENGTH="25"/>
```

Functions -

```
function tan(form) {
  form.display.value = trigPrecision(Math.tan(form.display.value));
}

function tanDeg(form) {
  form.display.value = trigPrecision(Math.tan(radians(form)));
}

function radians(form) {
  return form.display.value * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

with jQuery -

```
$("#button-tan").click(function(){
        if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
            if($("#button-mode").val() === 'DEG'){
                tan(this.form); // INSERT OTHER 'if' STATEMENT HERE FOR RAD ARRAY
            } 
            else{
                tanDeg(this.form); // INSERT OTHER 'if' STATEMENT HERE FOR DEG ARRAY
            }

        }
});
```

I would like to incorporate an array check within the `.click` function such that if the user input is contained in the array (`degArr` or `radArr` depending on the mode), the calculator returns `Undefined`. Now, I know how to display `Undefined` in the input display (`$('#disp').val('Undefined')`), but I cannot figure out how to configure an if statement that checks the relevant array. Is there a way to do so within the `#button-tan` function where I have commented?

Comment: Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the arrays on click and set a variable  if you find a matched value.

You can do something like this:

```
$("#button-tan").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var userInput = $('#disp').val();
var buttonMode = $('#button-mode').val();
var displayVal = '';
if (buttonMode === 'DEG') {
    var radFound = false;
    radArr.forEach(function(item) { // changed from degArr
        if (item === userInput) {
            radFound = true;
        }

        if (radFound) {
            displayVal = 'undefined';
        } else {
            tan(this.form);
        }
    });
} else {
    var degFound = false;
    degArr.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item === userInput) {
            degFound = true;
        }

        if (degFound) {
            displayVal = 'undefined';
        } else {
            tanDeg(this.form);
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Doesn't seem to work! The tan button does nothing now

Comment: There was a typo with the buttonMode var that caused it to error out, also you need to add a e.preventDefault(), to stop the button from taking the default action.

Comment: Her you can see a more refined version of this code mostly working, you will need to fine turn it to you needs but the logic is sound: https://jsbin.com/kecuba/edit?html,js,console,output  You need to be careful though as one array contains strings and the other contains floats.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` should work...

```
$("#button-tan").click(function(){
    if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
        if($("#button-mode").val() === 'DEG'){
            if (radArr.indexOf(Number(this.form)) > -1) {
                $('#disp').val('Undefined');
            } else {
                tan(this.form);
            }
        } 
        else{
            if (degArr.indexOf(Number(this.form)) > -1) {
                $('#disp').val('Undefined');
            } else {
                tanDeg(this.form);
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple object of a `Calculator` class, which keeps a reference to these arrays, and use like this. I changed some methods to receive the input as parameter rather than form.

```
$(function () {
  function Calculator()
  {
    var degInc; 
    this.degArr = []; 
    var radInc; 
    this.radArr = [];
    var PI = Math.PI;
    var radStart = (-91*PI/2);
    var radEnd = (91*PI/2);

     for (degInc = -8190; degInc <= 8190; degInc+=180) {
           this.degArr.push(degInc);
        }
     for (radInc = radStart; radInc <= radEnd; radInc+=PI) {
            var radIncFixed = radInc.toFixed(8);
           this.radArr.push(radIncFixed);
        }
  }

  var calc = new Calculator();

  function tan(input) {
    alert("tan called");
    var value = Math.tan(input.value);
    alert("tan called. value: " + value);
    input.value = value;
  }

  function tanDeg(input) {
    alert("tanDeg called");
    var value = Math.tan(radians(input));
    alert("tanDeg called. value: " + value);
    input.value = value;
  }

  function radians(input) {
    alert("radians called");
    var value = input.value * Math.PI / 180;
    alert("radians called. value: " + value);
    return value;
  }

  $("#button-tan").click(function(){

    alert (calc.degArr);
    alert (calc.radArr);

    var displayInput = $("#disp");

    alert("user input: " + displayInput.val());

    if (!isNaN(displayInput.val()))
    {
        if($("#button-mode").val() === 'DEG')
        {
          if (calc.radArr.indexOf(displayInput.val()) > -1)
          {
            alert("user input is in radArr");
          }
          else
          {
            alert("user input IS NOT in radArr");
            tan(displayInput);
          }
        } 
        else
        {
          if (calc.degArr.indexOf(displayInput.val()) > -1)
          {
            alert("user input is in degArr");
          }
          else {
            alert("user input IS NOT in degArr");
            tan(displayInput);
          }
        }
      }
      else
        alert("Not a number in input");
  });
});
```

If you wanna do some tests, I created a [JSFiddle demo here.](https://jsfiddle.net/waof85at/) Type -8190 in the first input, then click the button. It's gonna be inside the array. Then try typing **"DEG"** in the second input and clicking again, you'll notice code will check against another array (due to IFs). I couldn't make your auxiliar functions to calculate a value, but I think this helps you with your initial problem.